# React Router v6 Navigate with parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently, I have a problem when implementing React Router v6 (using 6.3.0)

Let say users have some flow like this

Participant --> View Participant Detail that accessed using

```
<Link to=('participant/xxx-guid') replace={true}>Detail</Link>
```

And in View Participant there is another link to edit some invoice that accessed using

```
<Link to=('./participant/xxx-guid/yyy-guid/edit-invoice') replace={true}>Detail</Link>
```

In edit Invoice page, that is accessed by url above. There is a problem that I notice.

1. The Participant Details is not listed on Browser History
2. After user submit the form, I put following function to bring the user back Participant Detail using  `` navigate(`/participant/xxx-guid`, {replace:true}); `` but the result is not as expected. Instead of the participant detail is rendered, the application redirect the page into list of participant.

Below are the routing declaration that I wrote on my application

```
const ParticipantRoutes = () => (
  <ErrorBoundaryRoutes>
    <Route index element={<Participant />} />
    <Route path="new" element={<ParticipantUpdate />} />
    <Route path=":id">
      <Route index element={<ParticipantDetail />} />
      <Route path=":id">
        <Route path="edit-invoice" element={<InvoiceUpdate />}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="invoice" element={<ParticipantInvoiceUpdate />} />
      <Route path="edit" element={<ParticipantUpdate />} />
      <Route path="delete" element={<ParticipantDeleteDialog />} />
    </Route>
  </ErrorBoundaryRoutes>
);
```

and Invoice route like

```
const InvoiceRoutes = () => (
  <ErrorBoundaryRoutes>
    <Route index element={<Invoice />} />
    <Route path=":id">
      <Route index element={<InvoiceDetail />} />
      <Route path="delete" element={<InvoiceDeleteDialog />} />
      <Route path="payment" element={<InvoicePaidDialog />} />
    </Route>
  </ErrorBoundaryRoutes>
);
```

Thank you!

**Updated on 2024-01-11 : Edit on Question**

Comment: Can you add a `StackBlitz` or `codesandbox` example?

Comment: You are navigating to the literal path `"/participant/${participantId}"`. If you want to ***inject*** a participant GUID then use the backtick `\`` character, e.g. ```"`/participant/${participantId}`"``` (*minus the quotes, sorry, code formatting in comments is not good*). The `generatePath` solution looks like it should have worked though. Can you [edit] to clarify what the issue/problem is in better detail? What is actually happening in the code now?

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, the route : `.../participant/*some-guid-participant*/*some-guid-participant-invoice*/edit-invoice`
refers to the component `InvoiceUpdate` and not `ParticipantInvoiceUpdate`

Moreover, do not forget to change `'` to ` when using string formatting :

```js
navigate(`/participant/${some-guid-participant}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I put the incorrect component. It should be InvoiceUpdate instead of ParticipantInvoiceUpdate